# My android app is not running in the emulator

Tags: android

Emulator window shows the app icon, but when i got it run, it says - unfortunately the app has stopped.
i created new projects but still it doesn't work.
please tell me a way out of this.

Comment: check your logcat and put here the detail of errors from logcat

Comment: yes, you will need to provide the error so you can get help

Comment: see the logcat for possible reason of app crash